# Structured Data tool Error - There was an error validating your markup

Tags: seo, wordpress, structured-data

Using WordPress with Avada Theme.

After a recent update googles Structured Data Testing tool is returning an error upon validating which was perfect before the update.

I have checked Google console search it has no errors and the site is working perfectly.

Just had a drop in ranking and I am trying to figure out the problem.

Has anyone had similar issues?

[image]

Comment: It is very unlikely that structure data caused a ranking drop.  Google has said they don't use structured data for ranking purposes, only for rich snippets.   See my blog: [SEO Myth: Structured data helps search engine rankings](https://blog.ostermiller.org/structured-data-seo/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your site's HTML is very broken.

You can check it via https://validator.w3.org/

**A bit of insight about structured data**

If you have invalid HTML it is difficult for Google to figure out which parts of the page belong together. This presents a problem for structured data because its purpose is to create semantics.

This is mostly a problem with microformats and RDFa because that markup is inlined in the HTML. It's less of an issue for JSON-LD. You appear to be using both.

**Troubleshooting your problem**

To begin troubleshooting this please try disabling the Rocket Lazy Load, then clear any caches, and then try the structured data testing tool again.

Unfortunately, invalid/broken HTML can be very common with page builder Wordpress themes because they are very prone to plugin conflicts.